# O que significa transition band em filtros passa-banda?

Tags: python, dsp

Olá, estou trabalhando em um filtro passa banda em python, e ao pesquisar encontrei este [link](https://plot.ly/python/fft-filters/), no qual afirma uma variável do código:

```
"b is the transition band also as a function of the sampling rate"
```

O que isso significa? E como faria para um para uma frequência de 360Hz ?

```
fL = 0.1
fH = 0.3
b = 0.08
N = int(np.ceil((4 / b)))
if not N % 2: N += 1  # Make sure that N is odd.
n = np.arange(N)

# low-pass filter
hlpf = np.sinc(2 * fH * (n - (N - 1) / 2.))
hlpf *= np.blackman(N)
hlpf = hlpf / np.sum(hlpf)

# high-pass filter 
hhpf = np.sinc(2 * fL * (n - (N - 1) / 2.))
hhpf *= np.blackman(N)
hhpf = hhpf / np.sum(hhpf)
hhpf = -hhpf
hhpf[(N - 1) / 2] += 1

h = np.convolve(hlpf, hhpf)
s = list(data['10 Min Std Dev'])
new_signal = np.convolve(s, h)
```

Comment: vc tem algum exemplo de filtro passa-banda ? poderia postar ?

Comment: Desculpe, infelizmente não..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É o que literalmente está dizendo, é a quantidade de frequências que está entre a curva de transição do filtro, iniciando de um estado e indo para o outro estado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem fica fácil de ver, a transição começou a ser aplicada por volta de `1500hz(1.5kHz)` e teve sua ação completamente efetiva em aproximadamente `2kHz`, ou seja teve aproximadamente `500Hz` de transição ...

O exemplo do site é tão básico que fica meio complicado alguém que está estudando entender como aplicar o filtro do seu código, só para deixar algo mais tangível eu escrevi um código que aplica as equações diretamente em um sinal de áudio, criei três sinais de áudios(senoides), cada senoide está em uma frequência diferente `200hz`, `400hz` e `800hz`, após criar os sinais eu Mixei todos para misturar ... ao aplicar `Fourier`, dá pra ver os 3 sinais com suas respectivas frequências:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então utilizando o filtro passa banda acima será que ele realmente funciona para remover sinais abaixo de `200Hz` e acima de `800Hz`, então em teoria o filtro teria que manter somente a senoide em `400Hz`, certo ?

Com um pouco de ruído na base da senoide, mas as outras foram removidas pelo filtro...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


#gerando sinal de teste
Fs = 44100
freq1 = 200
freq2 = 400
freq3 = 800
nsamples = 4096
sinal = np.arange(nsamples)
sinal1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq1 * sinal / Fs)
sinal2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq2 * sinal / Fs)
sinal3 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq3 * sinal / Fs)

sinalmix = sinal1 + sinal2 + sinal3;

#fim, sinal criado




#Inicio do filtro

fL = 350/Fs
fH = 450/Fs
b = 200/Fs
N = int(np.ceil((4 / b)))
if not N % 2: N += 1  # Make sure that N is odd.
n = np.arange(N)

# low-pass filter
hlpf = np.sinc(2 * fH * (n - (N - 1) / 2.))
hlpf *= np.blackman(N)
hlpf = hlpf / np.sum(hlpf)

# high-pass filter 
hhpf = np.sinc(2 * fL * (n - (N - 1) / 2.))
hhpf *= np.blackman(N)
hhpf = hhpf / np.sum(hhpf)
hhpf = -hhpf
hhpf[(N - 1) / 2] += 1

h = np.convolve(hlpf, hhpf)
sinalfiltred = np.convolve(sinalmix, h)

#Final do filtro 


#análise de Fourier no sinal Original e no Sinal Filtrado
AmplitudeJaneladaF=sinalfiltred*np.hamming(len(sinalfiltred)); 
FourierF=abs(np.fft.rfft(AmplitudeJaneladaF))

AmplitudeJaneladaO=sinalmix*np.hamming(len(sinalmix)); 
FourierO=abs(np.fft.rfft(AmplitudeJaneladaO))


NyquistTeorema = (Fs / 2)

MinFrequencia=NyquistTeorema / (len(sinalfiltred) / 2);

MinFrequencia2=NyquistTeorema / (len(sinalmix) / 2);

Frequencias=np.linspace(MinFrequencia, NyquistTeorema, num=(len(sinalfiltred) / 2))

Frequencias2=np.linspace(MinFrequencia2, NyquistTeorema, num=(len(sinalmix) / 2))

#Plot dos dois Sinais

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Fourier original')
plt.plot(Frequencias2[1:90],FourierO[1:90])


plt.figure(2)
plt.title('Fourier Filtrado')
plt.plot(Frequencias[1:110],FourierF[1:110])


plt.show()
```

Acima o código que cria os sons, aplica os filtros(copiado e colado o código do seu post essa parte), faz análise de Fourier para capturar as frequências e faz os plots, é praticamente a prova do conceito, estou filtrando tudo que estiver abaixo de `350Hz` e tudo que estiver acima de `450Hz` e utilizei uma banda de transição em `200Hz`...

Você verá que estou escolhendo as frequências e aplicando em função do sampling rate(taxa de amostragem `Fs=44100Hz`)